# Can't deserialize Gson object on Release mode

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit

Before I upgraded Gradle from version 4 to 5, everything worked on both Debug and Release mode.

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath 'com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:1.16'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:2.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.9.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$Deps.KOTLIN_VERSION"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.gradle.build-scan'
```

gradle-wrapper

```
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
//distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Now I've got an object which can't be deserialized.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

class EntityPost {
    @field:SerializedName("id") var id: String = ""
    @field:SerializedName("description") val description: String? = null
    @field:SerializedName("resource") val media: EntityMedia? = null
...
}
```

Only on release mode, as for the nested object EntityMedia, either itself or its properties are null, while other properties are fine.

```
class EntityMedia {
    @SerializedName("id") val resourceId: String? = null
    @SerializedName("contentType") val contentType: String? = null
}
```

I'm using RxJava2

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0"
```

If I cast the media variable to Any, the result is

```
{id=5612a7c54, contentType=video/mp4}
```

Comment: Did you add proguard rules? https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Comment: You... are... great!